# Default font - issues with Verdana

Tags: bug, design

Windows 7, Firefox, 100 DPI display.
I see the body text on EE.SE pages rendered in Verdana font.
I can tell this because of the notorious bug in this font,
namely broken kernings in particular sizes. Ironically this is 
mostly seen in the default size that is used on this site.
It looks horrible because of jumping spacings between letters and this cause
quite uncomfortable effect on eyes.

Example:

[image]

The CSS should be changed to "Arial" or "Segoe UI". I find Arial is better readable in general case, due to less spacings between letters.

Examples:

[image]

SegoeUI:
[image]

Comment: I'm sure it's an internet browser and operating system browser thing. I'm currently running Chrome on Mint 18.2 and my font is different from either of these. I don't there's much arbitration of a "default" font.

Comment: You could use a greasmokey script to change it with some work if it really bothers you. Its unlikely that you get this changed for everyone

Comment: @laptop2d yes I always use Stylish plugin with custom css  for all SE sites. I just wonder how windows users can be ok with the default :)  This font distortion  is so well seen and certainly affects the readability.

Comment: I'm fine with the current font